# Configuring spring cloud data flow with a servlet prefix

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have tried configuring Spring Cloud Data Flow (2.0.0.m2) with a prefix, such as:

`server.servlet.context-path=/scdf`

This does not work because, when you go to `http://localhost:9393/scdf/dashboard`, the javascript loaded up tries to go to `/security/info` (not `/scdf/security/info`).

I am pretty confident this is a bug; I've been reading through the UI code here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-ui, but don't think there is anyway around this beyond a code fix.

But let me ask here first!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a current limitation indeed. Both the RESTful endpoints and Dashboard are served from the same root. We redirect to `/dashboard` by default, so that collides and takes precedence even when a different context-path is set.

We wanted to eventually move all the RESTful endpoints to `/api` and the Dashboard at `/dashboard`, to be able to cleanly separate them both.

We are tracking this effort through [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-ui#747](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-ui/issues/747) and [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow#1581](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/1581).

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirming. I did miss these issues in looking. Apologies!

Answer (score 1):

Yes the `server.servlet.context-path` only configures the backend Spring App. I couldn't find anyway to do this nicely on both the front-end and backend. If you run it using docker compose, etc you could proxy all requests. Otherwise I looked at the codebase and I think the easiest way to configure the front-end as well is to edit the `proxy.conf.json` file, and append `/scdf/` to everything. Not ideal though.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, to work around this issue and run the dataflow server behind Proxy, a DNS entry (for example: scdf.example.com) was created and proxy rules are configured based on the DNS instead of contextpath. Hope this helps!